# Why do my Office 365 OAuth2 refresh tokens keep expiring so quickly?

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, refresh, office365, access-token

I'm aware that the Office 365 refresh tokens expire when the user changes their password, but I'm seeing them expire almost weekly for my customers.

Is there something I've misconfigured when setting up my OAuth2 app in Azure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, the access token lasts 1 hours, the refresh token lasts 14 days.

According to the document [Authorization Code Grant Flow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx), the lifetime of refresh token varies based on **policy settings**. In this case, you may check the Azure AD policy settings.

> The lifetime of the refresh token is not provided and varies based on
>   policy settings and the time when the authorization code grant is
>   revoked by Azure AD. The application should expect and handle cases when the request for a new access token fails. In that case, it should return to the code that requests a new access token.

When the access token expires, you can use the Refresh Token to Request a New Access Token. The response including a new access token and a new refresh token.

The old refresh token will last 14 days, as a workaround, you can use the new refresh token which will lasts another 14 days.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, where can I find the policy settings?  Is the refresh expiration a configuration option of some kind?

Comment: @jarcoal, have you tried to use the new refresh token to refresh the token, I've updated the workaround in my reply.

Comment: Ahhh, I didn't realize that a new refresh token can be returned and was not persisting it.  Thank you so much!  Is this documented somewhere?  It should be very clear to developers, as most of us are more familiar with Google where a refresh token is good forever (generally).

Comment: @JeffreyChen-MSFT if I understand your last para correctly, we could keep using refresh token forever (assuming we refresh the access token within 14 days), as long as we keep using the most recent refresh token. Please confirm. We're trying to avoid having the user reauthorize the app and starting all over with the auth code grant flow.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Sign-in Frequency settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/conditional-access/howto-conditional-access-session-lifetime).  If enabled, the new refresh tokens returned with access tokens will expire based on the last interactive login rather than when the new refresh token was issued.