# Webservice access to Sharepoint REST API

Tags: web-services, rest, sharepoint, oauth-2.0

i need to implement an Webservice (in PHP) which will be acting as a proxy for the Microsoft Sharepoint REST API. The Sharepoint is secured, but the Webservice should provide specific information to public (fe. a subset of fields from a specific list).

I played around with OAuth2 in the last days but it seems that there is now way to implement a automatic authentification flow that needs no interaction from a user (or i didn't found it yet).

My Webservice is registered as Azure App. I got an auth flow up and runing where i request an authorization_code (this one i always have to confirm manual in browser while redirecting) and this code i can use to get an access_token. With this access token i can access all data but until it's validity ends. Than i have to do manual interaction again for the authorization_code.

I'm missing something? Is there any good demo code? Or is the use case in general not solveable with Oauth2 (i'm new to oauth2...)

Comment: probably need the refresh token, take look at this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36463040/why-do-my-office-365-oauth2-refresh-tokens-keep-expiring-so-quickly